# Magento Store IDs & Order #s - Staging Area

Tags: magento, staging

Currently, I have one magento install that has 4 stores running in it:

Order IDs:
Tuga - 1
SBK - 3
Mole - 4
Loko - 5

All of these stores have one view each. I am wondering if I can use a new store view as a staging area without getting a new Order ID.

I'd like to be able to publicly test a new theme in this staging area. The orders that come through this staging area should be in line with the Tuga order #s.

Is this possible? Will I end up getting a new order ID (6, 7, etc..)

I ask this because our order software that pulls info from the sites only pulls orders from each Order ID that we list, if I have to add another, I have to purchase another license ($300+)

Any help or information is greatly appreciated! Please let me know if I did not explain this clearly!

Answer (score 0):

Check this table:

> sales_flat_order

Specifically:

```
SELECT
entity_id
store_id,
increment_id
FROM
sales_flat_order;
```

Magento assigns values from `eav_entity_store` as you create them.

You should play around in a local dev environment to setup new stores but when the first order is placed it will increment using the `eav_entity_store`.

To summarize, if you're attempting to prevent new entity_ids from being generated in sales_flat_order table for a specific store view that is not possible using a vanilla installation.